# Will Google's New +1 Count For SEO

Tags: seo, google, social-media, google-plus-one

I read somewhere that google's new +1 feature is going to affect google's search results. Apparently the more +1s you have, the better your site will rank in google. Is that true? And if it's true, how much will having a lot of "+1s" affect my site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I read something similar as well.

As far as I understand it +1 only works with users signed into Google Accounts, so it will depend on the number of people that use your site and who are logged into their google accounts at the same time.

+1 is part of Google's social play so if people +1 a site it is likely to have an impact their personal results in future and possibly that of there connections within other Google services. Its also feasible for Google to look at +1 as some sort of positive indicator for a site and in conjunction with a persons existing profile within Google services give that some form of weighting. I don't see that being much different to having a lot of people "like" or "tweet" about your site both of which are already used with the various search engines ( Google and Bing / Yahoo).

As +1 has not been rolled out yet with the site buttons etc. It's very much guess work as to the overall impact having none, some or a lot of +1's will have. If it was me i would focus on all the normal stuff with regard to running a good site while keeping an eye on +1 when released.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will count. Google's search algorithm is insanely sophisticated, with more signals than any single person can really grasp, and google didn't get to be the best in search by ignoring new potential ranking factors.

But of course it will not be as simple as "the more +1s, the stronger the site / better the page will rank for a query." That's too easy to game, and google's search engineers are not morons. I bet important factors are going to include the age/freshness of the +1s and their origin - whose accounts, how those accounts are connected to the site owners' accounts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Google +1 – with the launch of Google +1 it has been announced that +1 votes will count as a ranking factor. There are still penalty of sites who don’t seem to care. Inserting a +1 button is easier than a Facebook-like widget.

You can also check this url: http://thecopypasteblog.com/google-plus-button-seo