# How can the Google Plus one Button aid in SEO

Tags: seo, google, google-plus-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will Google's New +1 Count For SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13850/will-googles-new-1-count-for-seo)

I have setup the Google Plus One button on my website. I would like to know how it could affect the SEO of my pages. I heard that only on our friends' and contacts' computers, the results are improving. Or does it globally improve the rankings. I'm concerned about it because the JavaScript (yes the newest one) of the button slows down the site.If it is useful for global SEO only, I want to continue using it. Please advise.

Comment: I see that google quotes "get recommended on search". That might have answered my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google +1 button is definitely going to impact global search results. Google alludes to it in their [+1 button page](http://www.google.com/+1/button/)

> Your +1's can help friends, contacts, **and others on the web** find the best stuff when they search.

Additionally, they also mention that +1 counts may be displayed within search results even if no one you know has +1'd your pages. From [their blog](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/03/1s-right-recommendations-right-when-you.html):

> Say, for example, you’re planning a winter trip to Tahoe, Calif. When you do a search, you may now see a +1 from your slalom-skiing aunt next to the result for a lodge in the area. Or if you’re looking for a new pasta recipe, we’ll show you +1’s from your culinary genius college roommate. And even if none of your friends are baristas or caffeine addicts, we may still show you how many people across the web have +1’d your local coffee shop.

This may not directly influence global rankings, but like [microformats](http://schema.org/), it can encourage a user to click on your search results listing.

Comment: +1 Then I must forego a few seconds for the button. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Google +1 is another way to increase traffic on your site by making your site visible to google search. Well the answer may lie in the google webmasters tool, recently i have logged in to my Google Webmasters tool account and i have seen there a new link that says Google +1 metrics, this means GOogle is also measuring the +1's in your website. So i believe +1 has an effect with your rankings and SEO.